# How to mount Time Capsule from Raspberry Pi

Tags: mount

There is a 2TB Time Capsule on my home network (IP 192.168.0.1). How can I mount the Time Capsule's disk from my Raspberry Pi, automatically after reboots?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put it in fstab.

```
sudo su
mkdir /mnt/timecapsule
echo "//timeCapsuleIp/Data /mnt/timecapsule cifs user=timecapsuleUsername,pass=timecapsuleUserPassword,rw,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

Required `cifs-utils` package should be already provided on raspbian.

Of course change timecapsuleUsername and timecapsuleUserPassword. The uid=1000 sets owner of mounted files to user pi. If using other user check it's uid with `id -u username`. Check if "Data" folder is right for you - list resources by issuing command `smbclient -Uusername -I ip-address -L`.

Comment: I get this error when trying to mount: `mount error(115): Operation now in progress`. I can access the share fine with smbclient though. Any ideas?

Comment: Got it: I first tried with the `.local` name instead of the IP, does not seem to work reliably. Second, I needed to add `sec=ntlm` to the options. Now it works!

Comment: If `Disks Secure Shared` Disks `With a disk password` option is selected, then `user=` param would be ignored regardless of what it's set to

Comment: Just tested this on a Time Capsule running the latest (7.6.7) firmware to a Pi running OSMC. The key is the `sec=ntlm` and I can confirm that this works with disks secured with a device password as well as a disk password.

Answer (score 5):

I got adding sec=ntlm to the options, the complete command is:

```
sudo su
mkdir /mnt/timecapsule
echo "//timeCapsuleIp/Data /mnt/timecapsule cifs user= timecapsuleUsername,pass= timecapsuleUserPassword,rw,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

Then, run this command:

```
mount -a
```

You should no get any errors.

Answer (score 4):

Update for users of Raspberry Stretch v9. Note the addition of vers=1.0

```
//IPofTimeCapsule/PathWithinYourTimeCapsule /mnt/TimeCapsule cifs username=insert,password=insert,rw,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0 0 0
```

Comment: What do you mean with the line beginning with `//IPofTimeCapsule`?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I meant IP address of TimeCapsule.  For example, the line might read... //192.168.1.11/Data /mnt/TimeCapsule cifs username=bsmith, password=batman, rw, uid=1000, iocharset=utf8, sec=ntlm, vers=1.0 0 0

Answer (score 1):

For me, when using a disk password on the time capsule, it only worked when I added uid=504 (which is the userID used on the macintosh mainly using the timecapsule, not the uid used on the raspberry). When I didn't put uid=504 then I got "mount error(16): Device or resource busy" back from the time capsule.