# Mounting the Apple Time Capsule from Raspberry Pi

Tags: mount

I tried to use the information on the other two Posts with similar questions and wasn't able to figure it out. I'm still new to this.

I am trying to mount the Time Capsule so I can use the HDD on there to store files for my Raspberry Pi.

first I tried

```
echo "//timeCapsuleIp/Data /mnt/timecapsule cifs user=timecapsuleUsername,pass=timecapsuleUserPassword,rw,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

But that didn't work. And then I saw the mount fix using this code

```
//192.168.1.1/Time-Capsule /mnt/TimeCapsule cifs credentials=your_TimeCapsule_credentials_path],file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,rw,sec=ntlm   0   0
```

but I still wasn't able to get it to work.

I am also not sure how to find the username for the Time Capsule as when I use it from the Macbook it only asks for a passwork and not any username.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this out, but you might want to check out this: [How to mount Time Capsule from Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8386/how-to-mount-time-capsule-from-raspberry-pi)

You'll need to install cifs-utils.

Comment: Odd, I have my TimeCapsule mounted just fine.  On my macbook pro, my username is jwiggins.  Here is the last line of my /etc/fstab file: **//10.0.5.1/Data /mnt/tc cifs user=jwiggins,pass=****,rw,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0** I had to create the /mnt/tc directory.  The password is one I setup on the TimeCapsule when I first installed it.