# Mount AirPort Time Capsule - Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: networking, mount

I've got a Raspberry Pi 2 on which I run Plex Media Server.

Now I want to mount my AirPort Time Capsule, where I save all the movies and tv shows, to my raspberry Pi 2. Then I should be able to chose the media folder as the source folder used in Plex.

The Raspberry Pi is directly connected to the AirPort Time Capsule via Ethernet. 
Anyone could help me out?

I've tried multiple google search results but didn't work out for me so far.

Here are some information of my setup:
AirPort Time Capsule 2 TB:

```
ip: 77.22.XX.XX
Lan ip: 192.168.XX.XX
Drive name: Data
```

Drive access with device password - not user specific - need to change that?

I've tried this: [How to mount Time Capsule from Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8386/how-to-mount-time-capsule-from-raspberry-pi)

But it gives me a mount error 13: "access denied"

Edit: I've set drive access to user specific now. If I go to the file management on the raspberry - go to - network I can see my network shared devices. I see the Airport Time Capsule in 3 different versions. Two of them don't require a user/password but are empty and the third one offers me to enter user and password but gives me 2 error notifications: 1.) error kFPAuthContinue from server and 2.) selected location is not mounted. The one with the password has the following information: name: AirPort Time Capsule (Datei-Freigabe) | location: network:/// | destination file: afp://AirPort-Time-Capsule.local:548/ | if that helps in any way

What exactly am I doing wrong? Which commands do I need to enter. 
Please be nice I'm an absolute noob ;) 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> The Raspberry Pi is directly connected to the AirPort Time Capsule via Ethernet.

That step is your primary problem.  The Time Capsule is not designed to be plugged into a computer directly through ethernet.  It would be significantly more complicated to make it work.

The Time Capsule should be plugged into a router (or connected wirelessly), and then mounted over your network.

Comment: Let me get that correct this time. My Airport Time Capsule is connected via the WAN port to my internet provider modem which is set to bridge mode so my airport time capsule handles all the stuff including port forwarding for the plex server. The raspberry is connected to the airport time capsule via Ethernet in one of its LAN ports to get the necessary internet connection.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: @Klatti: my apologies, I forgot about this question... I'm looking up what it could be, but it has me a little stumped. I haven't been able to find much documentation for the airport being used to connect network devices.

Comment: No idea whether this is something special, but there _are_ time capsules which have multiple Ethernet ports. One of them is the WAN port that should be linked up to an internet connection. However, these time capsules can in fact be used as routers and therefore an RPi (or any other device) can be plugged directly into it - just not into the WAN port (well it can, but it'd be of little use then unless the RPi is the router to the internet, for example).

Comment: The tc will assign itself a network address as should the pi and announce itself using bonjour which avahi understands.