# How to mount USB Drive attached to Time Capsule

Tags: pi-3, mount

I am setting up my Pi-3 as a Plex Server and I am having trouble mounting my drive. The drive with all of my media is called 2TB Passport and I have followed information from another thread and I have been able to mount the Data folder that is located on the Time Capsule itself, but I have been unable to get the USB drive to mount. It gives me errors saying Passport does not exist... Here is the code I've been using. The user doesn't make a difference because the device is protected with a device password and there is no user input.

`sudo su
mkdir /mnt/timecapsule
echo "//***.***.***.***/2TB Passport /mnt/timecapsule cifs user=blank,pass=**********,rw,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0" >> /etc/fstab`

Changing "2TB Passport" to "Data" is what allowed me to mount the Data folder and that works perfectly, but for some reason it doesn't want to mount the USB drive. Any help would be appreciated! I'm a new Pi user and have loved working on this project so far.

Comment: Try mounting `//***.***.***.***/2TB\040Passport`. The `\040` is octal for 32 which is the ASCII code for the space character.

Comment: Why are you trying to `echo` that bizarre string to `/etc/fstab`. Just edit the file, (and list contents in your question).

Comment: Thanks David, I'll that when I get home today. I'm using echo because that's what this thread used and it worked for them. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8386/how-to-mount-time-capsule-from-raspberry-pi/23167#23167

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David's comment got it working, but the drive still was not mounting automatically on startup. After a bit more research I figured out I needed to get into the Pi Configuration tool and under System--> Network at Boot --> Check the Wait for Network box. Now it mounts on startup properly. The lines that finally got it going were

```
    sudo su
    mkdir /mnt/timecapsule
    echo "//TIMECAPSULEIPADDRESS/2TB\040Passport /mnt/timecapsule cifs user=blank,pass=TIMECAPSULEPASSWORD,rw,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because the label is in two words. Try using quotes

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is adding a line at the end of the file `/etc/fstab`. That is what the shell operator `>>` does. If you have run this several times, your `/etc/fstab` will probably look strange. Open it in an editor hand have a look. You do *not* want duplicated, unnecessary or erroneous lines in this file!

The reason this doesn't work as you expect is, as has been pointed out, that a space character is interpreted as the start of one argument and the beginning of the next. That means that rather than mounting `//***.***.***.***/2TB Passport` to `/mnt/timecapsule`, this line tries to mount `//***.***.***.***/2TB` to `Passport` (with the fstype `/mnt/timecapsule`), which, of course, fails.

There are several ways to tell the system that the space is a part of the name, rather than the end of an argument. This is referred to as "escaping" the space.

One way is using single or double quotes, like so:

```
"/***.***.***.***/2TB Passport" /mnt/timecapsule cifs user=blank,pass=**********,rw,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

another is to escape a single character with a `\`, like so:

```
/***.***.***.***/2TB\ Passport /mnt/timecapsule cifs user=blank,pass=**********,rw,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

There are other ways as well.