# How to mount Apple Time Capsule to Raspberry Stretch version 9

Tags: mount

Tried to update related article but closed to members with less than 10 merits.  So, this isn't a question.  Instead, it's an update to article below.

[How to mount Time Capsule from Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8386/how-to-mount-time-capsule-from-raspberry-pi)

Had to make adjustment to account for Raspberry Stretch v9. Note the addition of vers=1.0

//IPofTimeCapsule/PathWithinYourTimeCapsule /mnt/TimeCapsule cifs username=insert,password=insert,rw,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0 0 0

Comment: I think everyone's interests would be best served if you added your answer above as a new answer to the original question you've referenced. Benefit to you is that upvotes to your new answer will add to your "merits". Benefits to all others are that they get all of the latest information in one location.

Comment: @Seamus ... OP needs 10 rep to answer referenced protected question. ... Referenced question is dated 2013... Answers getting a little long in the tooth.

Comment: @RubberStamp: Yeah - appreciate the answers are old & would benefit from an update - it's why I made my suggestion. It's one of those "awkward situations" the rules create. I'll post something to Meta; sometimes they can help.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! The question is now "unprotected. Please feel free to post an answer there,pay attention to code formatting, and try to elaborate on why your solution is a relevant answer. Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Obviously this "question" will be deleted in time as it is no question.